# How to send duplicate POST parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I'm attempting to write an alternative UI for a website I commonly use. I'm writing it with Node.js using `request` and `cheerio` to scrape the web pages of data.

However, the problem occurs when I attempt to send a POST request against this site. I want to retrieve the list of classes here without going through this page first, but the normal post parameters shown in the devtools are structured like this:

```
sel_subj:dummy
bl_online:FALSE
sel_day:dummy
term:201630
sel_subj:ACTG
sel_inst:ANY
sel_online:
sel_crse:
begin_hh:0
begin_mi:0
end_hh:0
end_mi:0
```

I can modify any other value (`term`, `sel_crse`, etc), but the `sel_subj` doesn't have a compatible value, so the server just goes with the default value.

I've been trying different values for the `form` Object parameter in `request`, but none of these have worked:

```
sel_subj: ["M", "dummy"]
sel_subj: ["dummy", "M"]
sel_subj: "M"
sel_subj: "dummy,M"
sel_subj: "M,dummy"
sel_subj: "dummy M"
sel_subj: "M dummy"
sel_subj: "dummy, M"
sel_subj: "M, dummy"
```

I'm trying to figure out what a duplicate field in the POST request means, what the server expects, and how to reproduce that with `request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If parameter names can be duplicated, the request body can be designed by yourself:

```
var headers = {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
var body = [];

var params = [
    { sel_subj:'dummy' }, // duplicates 
    { bl_online:false },
    { sel_day:'dummy' },
    { term:'201630'},
    { sel_subj:'ACTG'}, // duplicates 
    { sel_inst:'ANY'},
    { sel_online: null},
    { sel_crse: null},
    { begin_hh:0},
    { begin_mi:0},
    { end_hh:0},
    { end_mi:0}
];

params.forEach( function(p) {
    body.push( require('querystring').stringify(p) );
});

var r = request.post({  url:'http://localhost/api/', 
                        headers: headers, 
                        body:body.join('&')
                     });
```

Comment: Holy crap that worked! I thought about forming the request body manually, but wasn't sure what kind of format it should be in. Thanks